# Displaying data in Blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

in my controller, I pass my template a list of projects

```
$projects = Project::all();
return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
```

Now a Project has one client, and a client belongs to a project.  If I loop my Projects within my view, I get the following data

```
#attributes: array:11 [▼
    "id" => "25"
    "jobNumber" => "J0001"
    "projectName" => "Some Name"
    "clientId" => "1"
    "clientContact" => "Some Contact"
    "contactEmail" => "email@email.co.uk"
    "status" => "Email"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2016-04-25 14:15:19"
    "updated_at" => "2016-04-26 10:05:06"
]
```

As you can see, the clientId is 1.  This links to a particular client.  Is there any way to get the client name using this ID?  I know how to do it in the controller, but I can't pass a variable for each project which has the clients name, this would be too much. As it stands, I am passing the view all of the projects, and each of these has a clientId.  Somehow I need to get the named based off this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you make a relationship in model as so:

**Project:**

```
public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Project');
    }
```

If you did, you can get to the client you need by simply calling `Project::find($id)->client`

If you want to forward it through controller, you can do it like:

```
$projects = Project::with('client');
return view('project.index', compact('projects'));
```

Which will nest client JSON under project.

**EDIT:**

However if I understood correctly, your problem is displaying it in a view without the need to do hundereds of variables. If you're using blade for your views, you can do it with foreach loop like so:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    {{$project->client->name}}
@endforeach
```

And you will simply traverse through all the projects

Comment: Hi, the relationships are there.  The thing is though, what you have posted needs to be done in the controller.  When I am passing the view all of the projects, I cant really do what you suggest because it means having a new variable for each project

Comment: Nicely copying my answer.

Comment: Really? Check the time before saying something stupid

Comment: Blade part? You don't have the loop, you don't have the controller return, and you sure don't have an explanation. The question was about returning all of the projects, not one

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Seeing as you created a model for projects.

You can define a relationship inside that model to clients.

It will all depend on the relationship you wish it to have. Can a project have multiple clients for example.

Assuming one project has one client.

```
 /**
 * Get list of clients for project
 * @return object
 */
public function client()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Project');
}
```

and then inside your blade template you can call

```
{{ $project->client->name }}
```