# display data from database into my blade page

Tags: database, laravel

> this is my Payment **Model** code

```
    function Payment_Professor(){
    return $this->hasMany("App\Payment_Professor","professor_id");
}

function Payment_Student(){
    return $this->hasMany("App\Payment_Student","student_id")
}

function Professor(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Professor","professor_id");
}

function Student(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Student","student_id");
}
```

> this is my payment_student **Model** code

```
   function Payment(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Payment");
}

 function formation(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Formation","formation_id");
}

function Student(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Student","student_id");
}
```

> this is my student ***Model***

```
     function presences(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Presence');
}

function payments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Payments');
}

 function Payment_Student(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Payment_Professor');
}
```

i want to display student payment from data base into  the blade page

> **balde.php** code

```
    @foreach($students as $student)
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
```

> this is my **controller** code

```
 public function index()
{
    $formations = Formation::all();
    $payments = Payment_Professor::all();
    $payments_s = Payment_Student::all();
        //merge two collections
    //$payments->merge('$payments_s');
    $students = Student::all();
    $professors = Professor::all();
    return view('payment.index', compact('payments','students','formations','professors','payments_s'));

}
```

what should i write inside the `<td>` and `<th>` tags, and is there anything wrong with my code  ? 
i hope my question is clear ? this is my first time in stack over flow

Comment: what data are you sending to you blade? please, show your controller

Comment: Welcome, Mohamed Midou. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before submitting your problem.

Comment: $payments_s = Payment_Student::all();
return view('payment.index', compact('payments','students','formations','professors','payments_s'));
this is my controller @Vrian7

Comment: @RashedHasan thanks man

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying data in Blade template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861597/displaying-data-in-blade-template)

Comment: that didn't work mate